# Java Server not able to encrypt/decrypt data with Blackberry's AESkey

Tags: java, encryption, blackberry, java-me, aes

I am developing a BlackBerry application where the server is in Java. Whenever AES encrypted data is sent to server along with PKCS5 Formatting,The server gets bad padding exception while decrypting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the Blackberry or the server code? Have you tried using the standard JCE classes? something like this:

`Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(yourKeyBytes, "AES");
aes.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] cleartext = aes.update(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.length);`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're doing the padding etc in the right order first: pad then encrypt, decrypt then unpad.

- Check the transmitted data length and make sure it's a multiple of blocksize.
- Make sure blocksize is consistent in all the calls.
- Make sure your crypto provider settings are exactly matching.